How to Find and Replace footer string using OpenXML: My solution
I found it hard to get any solution to FindAndReplace text in the footer of a document so after figuring it out myself I thought that maybe my solution could be of use to someone else.
I tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, after getting errors trying to use it and seeing other developers recommending to stay away from Microsoft.Office.Interop and use OpenXML instead I decided to go that way.

This is the way I go through the document and replace text instances that match a specified string.
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using Text = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text;

private static void FindAndReplace(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string findText, string replaceWithText)
        {
            foreach (Text text in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Text>())
            {
                if (text.Text.Contains(findText))
                {
                    text.Text = text.Text.Replace(findText, replaceWithText);
                }
            }

            foreach (var footerPart in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts)
            {
                foreach (Text text in footerPart.Footer.Descendants<Text>())
                {
                    if (text.Text.Contains(findText))
                    {
                        text.Text = text.Text.Replace(findText, replaceWithText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

This is how the method "FindAndReplace" is implemented in my project.
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    foreach ((string Find, string Replace) map in stringMappings)
    {
        FindAndReplace(wordDoc, map.Find, map.Replace);
    }

    if (wordDoc.CanSave)
    {
        wordDoc.Save();
    }
}

If you wonder how i fill my "stringMappings".
//Keep in mind this code snippet lacks further logic
List<(string Find, string Replace)>? stringMappings = new();

    string? stringFind = //some value

    string? stringReplace = //some value

        if (stringFind == "[DATE]")
        {
            stringReplace = System.DateOnly.FromDateTime(System.DateTime.Now).ToString();
        }

        stringMappings.Add((Find: stringFind, Replace: stringReplace));

